# How can I efficiently save a python pandas dataframe in hdf5 and open it as a dataframe in R?

Tags: python, r, pandas, data.table, hdf5

I think the title covers the issue, but to elucidate:

The [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) python package has a DataFrame data type for holding table data in python. It also has a convenient interface to the [hdf5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) file format, so pandas DataFrames (and other data) can be saved using a simple dict-like interface (assuming you have [pytables](http://pytables.org) installed)

```
import pandas 
import numpy
d = pandas.HDFStore('data.h5')
d['testdata'] = pandas.DataFrame({'N': numpy.random.randn(5)})
d.close()
```

So far so good. However, if I then try to load that same hdf5 into R I see things aren't so simple:

```
> library(hdf5)
> hdf5load('data.h5')
NULL
> testdata
$block0_values
         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 1.498147 0.8843877 -1.081656 0.08717049 -1.302641
attr(,"CLASS")
[1] "ARRAY"
attr(,"VERSION")
[1] "2.3"
attr(,"TITLE")
[1] ""
attr(,"FLAVOR")
[1] "numpy"

$block0_items
[1] "N"
attr(,"CLASS")
[1] "ARRAY"
attr(,"VERSION")
[1] "2.3"
attr(,"TITLE")
[1] ""
attr(,"FLAVOR")
[1] "numpy"
attr(,"kind")
[1] "string"
attr(,"name")
[1] "N."

$axis1
[1] 0 1 2 3 4
attr(,"CLASS")
[1] "ARRAY"
attr(,"VERSION")
[1] "2.3"
attr(,"TITLE")
[1] ""
attr(,"FLAVOR")
[1] "numpy"
attr(,"kind")
[1] "integer"
attr(,"name")
[1] "N."

$axis0
[1] "N"
attr(,"CLASS")
[1] "ARRAY"
attr(,"VERSION")
[1] "2.3"
attr(,"TITLE")
[1] ""
attr(,"FLAVOR")
[1] "numpy"
attr(,"kind")
[1] "string"
attr(,"name")
[1] "N."

attr(,"TITLE")
[1] ""
attr(,"CLASS")
[1] "GROUP"
attr(,"VERSION")
[1] "1.0"
attr(,"ndim")
[1] 2
attr(,"axis0_variety")
[1] "regular"
attr(,"axis1_variety")
[1] "regular"
attr(,"nblocks")
[1] 1
attr(,"block0_items_variety")
[1] "regular"
attr(,"pandas_type")
[1] "frame"
```

Which brings me to my question: ideally I would be able to save back and forth from R to pandas. I can obviously write a wrapper from pandas to R (I think... though I think if I use a pandas [MultiIndex](https://web.archive.org/web/20110926002307/http://pandas.sourceforge.net/indexing.html) that might become trickier), but I don't think I can easily then use that data back in pandas. Any suggestions?

Bonus: what I *really* want to do is use the [data.table](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) package in R with a pandas dataframe (the keying approach is suspiciously similar in both packages). Any help on that one greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Doesn't `testdata$block0_values` return the values you saved from the panda?

Comment: The problem is then being able to reopen again in pandas (see the later part of my question). I can convert to an R data.frame (or data.table) do some manipulations, but then I can't save back to pandas easily (without another, probably more complicated, wrapper).

Comment: I think what you're asking about would be very useful. For now, would it be acceptable to use something like this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html or perhaps even use the R bridge support in recent ipython? (http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/extensions/rmagic.html)

Answer (score 8):

If you are still looking at this, take a look at this post on google groups. It shows how to exchange data between pandas/R via HDF5.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/pydata/0LR72GN9p6w

Comment: Amazing, the first time I read this I didn't think it would go anywhere, but I just came across this again and it looks like progress has been made, particularly since it's now in the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#external-compatibility. Will test and give you credit if it works ;)

Comment: Sadly I couldn't quite get it to work, and R's hdf5 loading seems to take ages. I'm now using the new fread function in data.table: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/New-function-fread-in-v1-8-7-td4653745.html

Answer (score 3):

It would make sense to dropdown to pytables and store/get your data there.

Ultimately a DataFrame is a dict of Series which is what an HDF5 Table is. There are limitations on the translation due to incompatible dtypes but for numerical data it should be straight forward.

The way pandas stores its HDF5 is viewed more like a binary blob. It has to support all the nuances of a DataFrame which HDF5 does support cleanly.

https://github.com/dalejung/trtools/blob/master/trtools/io/pytables.py

Has some that kind of pandas/hdf5 munging code.

Comment: So you recommend writing a custom compatibility layer in pytables between pandas and R? I guess I need to figure out which has the simpler HDF5 format (R or pandas) and make that my basic datatype, then provide a converter on either end whenever I read or write.

Comment: Yes. You could conceivably write an R adapter to read/write pandas hdf semantically. But it seems easier to create a semantic HDF and have simple wrappers on both ends.

Answer (score 2):

How to write a dataframe in HDF5 so it can be read in R is now in the Pandas documentation:
http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#external-compatibility

Comment: Yeah I already linked there in my comment on the first answer. Sadly it's not a very efficient library in my own personal tests (as compared with data.table's fread), but perhaps I should give it another try. Thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [feather](https://github.com/wesm/feather), built by Wes and Hadley to solve the problem of transferring data between R and Python efficiently.

Python

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import feather as ft

df = pd.DataFrame({'N': np.random.randn(5)})
ft.write_dataframe(df, 'df.feather')
```

R

```
library(data.table)
library(feather)

dt <- data.table(read_feather("df.feather"))
dt
           N
1: 0.2777700
2: 1.4083377
3: 1.2940691
4: 0.8221348
5: 1.8552908
```

Comment: Nice suggestion! It's not hdf5 but arguably solves the basic workflow I wanted. Hmmm... need to decide whether to accept this answer as it does not directly answer the stated question but more deeply suggests a way to fix the general workflow I was hoping for.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `csv` files as the common data format. Both R and python pandas can easily work with that. You might lose some precision, but if this is a problem depends on your specific problem.

Comment: Yes of course, but that would mean I then lose the speed and convenience of the hdf5 format. R is super slow at parsing big text files (which is why I often use STATA's dta format for big data in R). I'd rather not write code to write to dta in python (there is a reader available in the statsmodels package).

Comment: Ironically enough that's now what I do because of data.table's super fast fread function for csv's. Sorry for the previous down vote.

Comment: @GriffithRees You could mark my answer as the correct one to atone for the downvote ;)

Comment: @Paul But, your answer is not the correct one. CSV simply isn't a practical solution, nor a good one architecturally, nor a creative one.

Comment: @GriffithRees, seems like there is still no progress and I have been bugged with this issue forever. I've started to working on my own dedicated binary data format for data frames that is compatible with R, Python's Pandas, C#/F#'s Deedle and Scala's Saddle.I will post a link if I ever finish my project.

Comment: @uday Are you doing this in a public repository somewhere? I'd have use for something like this, too.

Comment: @filmor, I'll put it in a public repository in a month's time. I am done writing the R and Pandas pieces, but trying to make the R code faster by using `Rcpp`.