# Preferred data format for R dataframe

Tags: python, r, dataframe

I am writing a data-harvesting code in Python. I'd like to produce a data frame file that would be as easy to import into R as possible. I have full control over what my Python code will produce, and I'd like to avoid unnecessary data processing on the R side, such as converting columns into factor/numeric vectors and such. Also, if possible, I'd like to make importing that data as easy as possible on the R side, preferably by calling a single function with a single argument of file name.

How should I store data into a file to make this possible?

Comment: Hi liori, this looks like it is not a statistics question (see the scope of stats.SE as given in the FAQ) but a purely R question, in which case it should be migrated to stackoverflow, where it's on-topic.

Comment: There are already some related questions on SO with the `r` tag there that may be of some use to you. If none seem to be any help you might like to edit your question (which will likely be migrated there) to add some explicit details (e.g. how big the data is, what data types you'll need to end up with in the data frame) and seek a more specific response.

Comment: @Glen_b: Ah, sorry. Could you link the related SO questions? I couldn't find anything… or maybe my queries weren't using proper keywords.

Comment: Exactly which questions are most relevant to you depends on details I don't have (but which I presume you do). As an example, it may be that the questions that relate to rpy2 have some relevance, or maybe questions that relate to importing databases are more relevant. Sorry I can't be more directly helpful - if there were more details, perhaps.

Comment: I voted to close because of the topic; I imagine this will go to SO.  But to get you started have you read http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html?

Comment: @PeterEllis: yes, I did. It seems that there are thousands of ways to adapt R into reading different fileformats, each of the way seem to require data introspection and several switches to make it work, caring about escape characters, encoding, separators and such. I don't see any “native” or “preferred” format though, one that would also allow me to add metadata like column type, and one where I'd be sure the data are imported correctly without the hassle of inspecting the file.

Comment: @Glen_b: the columns are strings (short ones like a line of text and longer ones like a paragraph or two), enumerations (factor in R lingo?), timespans in hours and money values (integers and floats). There are also missing values in the data too (NAs in R lingo?).

Comment: You will need to beware R's default behavior with reading in strings, which is generally to convert them to factors (which behavior is easily altered). One possibility you might consider is to write out the equivalent of a `dump` (which can be `source`d) or a `dput` (which you can `dget`).

Comment: I don't think this is answerable, as currently stated. I suppose it's possible you could dig into the R Internals and figure out how to write a serialized object from Python that could be loaded via `load`, but that seems like a lot of unnecessary work. I would just write a delimited text file and be done with it.

Comment: @liori, head(), tail() and str() are good for inspecting datasets quickly.

Comment: @joran: no need to re-implement R's serialization system in Python when you can just use R's own implementation from Python with rpy2.

Answer (score 4):

You can write data to CSV using http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html Python's `csv` module, then it's a simple matter of using `read.csv` in R. (See `?read.csv`)

When you read in data to R using `read.csv`, unless you specify otherwise, character strings will be converted to factors, numeric fields will be converted to numeric. Empty values will be converted to `NA`.

First thing you should do after you import some data is to look at the `?str` of it to ensure the classes of data contained within meet your expectations. Many times have I made a mistake and mixed a character value in a numeric field and ended up with a factor instead of a numeric.

One thing to note is that you may have to set your own NA strings. For example, if you have "-", ".", or some other such character denoting a blank, you'll need to use the `na.strings` argument (which can accept a vector of strings ie, `c("-",".")`) to `read.csv`.

If you have date fields, you will need to convert them properly. R does not necessarily recognize dates or times without you specifying what they are (see `?as.Date`)

If you know in advance what each column is going to be you *can* specify the class using `colClasses`.

A thorough read through of `?read.csv` will provide you with more detailed information. But I've outlined some common issues.

Comment: +1. I also often use CSV as a common format when needing to pass data between Python and R. It is not the best solution to all situations (e.g., very large data files) but in practice it is working fine for most of them.

Comment: I was thinking about this more, and if he could call Rpy directly from python he may be able to use R's built in serialization (readRDS, saveRDS) those are super fast and maintain their formats perfectly.

Comment: Yes (that's in the comments for the question).

Answer (score 4):

Brandon's suggestion of using CSV is great if your data isn't enormous, and particularly if it doesn't contain a whole honking lot of floating point values, in which case the CSV format is extremely inefficient.

An option that handled huge datasets a little better might be to construct an equivalent DataFrame in [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and use its facilities to dump to hdf5, and then open it in R that way. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278347/how-can-i-efficiently-save-a-python-pandas-dataframe-in-hdf5-and-open-it-as-a-da) for an example of that.

This other approach feels like overkill, but you could also directly transfer the dataframe in-memory to R using [pandas's experimental R interface](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html) and then save it from R directly.